# How to create named autoresetevent in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization

I need to synchronize two applications by using a named event. But neither AutoResetEvent nor ManualResetEvent contains constructor with a name for event (only initial state). I can open existing named event through static method OpenExisting in AutoResetEvent or ManualResetEvent class, but can't create It! I don't want to use native WinAPI CreateEvent function for It, unless I know precisely of not existing of other ways.

Comment: You'd use a `Mutex` wouldn't you?

Answer (score 30):

I found a solution by myself. That is:

```
EventWaitHandle handle = 
    new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "testRemoteServer");
```

Comment: I have found the solution a bit after posting this question by chance. I could delete this answer at all, but may be someone thinks this information useful for yourself. P.S.: Forbidden to mark self question as accepted :)

Comment: Hi, I think the time limit on accepting your own answer has expired now :)